# Error creating new symfony project

Tags: php, linux, symfony, ubuntu, curl

On a fresh install of Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) I run the following commands in preparation:

**Update app center**: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

**Install lamp server**: `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

**Install curl**: `sudo apt-get install curl`

**Install php5-curl**: `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`

From this point I follow the instructions from the current Symfony installation instructions from the beginning [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html):

```
sudo curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

When I try to create my new project 'projectX' with `symfony new projectX` I get the following error returned:

```
/usr/local/bin/symfony: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/usr/local/bin/symfony: line 1: `<!DOCTYPE html>'
```

Out of desperation I have tried running it sudo as well but then get:

```
/usr/local/bin/symfony: 2: /usr/local/bin/symfony: Syntax error: newline unexpected
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You might try the alternative, use composer to get symfony.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look into the file with `head /usr/local/bin/symfony`. It seems you didn't download the phar file. Instead you got a html error page saved with curl.

Comment: Thanks @Pazi ツ I haven't tried it yet but it makes a lot of sense.... although I'm not sure why `sudo curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony` did not download the .phar file?

Comment: Hey @Pazi ツ, I've deleted the file I had downloaded (which was an error page as you mentioned) and tried (three times) to reinstall but each time the file in /usr/local/bin/ is just called 'symfony' without an file extension and is just the html error page again. My curl command is the same as in the instructions so not sure what the problem could be?

Comment: What error is located in the file? Rename it for symfony.html and open it in a browser.

Comment: I've just tried downloading again after getting home and it now works! I don't know what the problem was so can't give any leads for others with the same problem sorry!